# Understanding operators in C

Tags: c, operators

I am struck on a basic problem with operators. Here is the problem

```
int i=3, j=2, k=1, m;
m = ++i || ++j  && ++k;
printf("%d %d %d %d", i, j, k, m);
```

As i worked on this and evaluated the ans as

> 4 3 2 1

But C is not happy with my ans and evaluates the above as

> 4 2 1 1

But i dont understand how. Why ++j is doesn't updates the value of j. And also ++k doesn't updates the value of k.
Anybody here please explain this how it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 m = ++i || ++j  && ++k;
```

The `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||`, so this is equivalent to:

```
 m = ++i || (++j && ++k);
```

Both `&&` and `||` are short-circuit operators; if the left operand determines the result, the right operand is not evaluated.  Since `++i` (which yields `4`) is "truthy", the right operand `(++j && ++k)` is not evaluated, and `j` and `k` are not incremented.  So `i` becomes `4`, and `j` and `k` retain their initial values of `2` and `1`, respectively.

The result of the `||` operator is either `0` (for false) or `1` (for true); since the condition is true, the value `1` is assigned to `m`.

Result:

```
4 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 5):

In C, `||` is a [short-circuit operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This means when evaluating the expression `a || b`, it will only evaluate `b` if `a` is false. If `a` is true, then the expression will always be true regardless of `b`.

Since `++i` gives a truthy value, `++j  && ++k` will not be evaluated.

Comment: Also, since "true" is "1", the value `1` is assigned to the variable `m`.

Comment: thanks.. so i now i understood how it works. The actual problem was of short-circuit operator.